# AzDO YAML pipeline, trigger on stage complete

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In a YAML multi-stage pipeline, is it possible to trigger another pipeline on completion of a given stage, not the entire pipeline? e.g.

Pipeline A may have stages: Build => Test => Deploy Env 1 => Deploy Env 2

I want pipeline B to trigger after 'Deploy Env 1' completes.

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your're only way is to use REST API to trigger pipeline B in a last step of `Deploy Env 1` stage.

Please check this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#build)

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1
```

You can create a topic on [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com) but it will take time until we get this.

Comment: Hello, thanks for quick response. I'll take this as the accepted answer since there is little alternative. I'll go over to the developer community and start the ball rolling at least.